# C++, How do you call a derived member function from a base class?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

The original programmer had this idea that seems to work on whatever compiler he was using, but doesn't work so well in VS C++.  The practice looks very questionable to me.

He's got a generic base class called `mathObject` that has a lot of common math functions.  On top of that, he's got a class called `Cosmos` and on top of that, another one called `QuintCosmos`.

The general idea is that he wants to call a member function that has the same signature from either `Mathobject` or `Cosmos` or `QuintCosmos`.  He's trying to cast it to

```
typedef void (Mathobject::*moDerivs) (const double, const double*, double*)
```

So, to recap, he can have function with this signature anywhere in this hierarchy and he wants to tell a third class (an Ordinary Differential Equation, ODE, Solver), to use a function with this signature.

```
hnext = Miscmath::odeint(&QuintCosmos::propagateHistoryInTau, this);
```

In the `odeint()` method, he calls this function like so.

```
double Miscmath::odeint(moDerivs derivs, Mathobject* mo)
{
    (mo->*derivs)(x, y, dydx);
}
```

This fails to compile in VS C++ with

> error C2664: 'double Miscmath::odeint(moDerivs,Mathobject *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__thiscall QuintCosmos::* )(const double,const double *,double *)' to 'moDerivs'

The original author tried to cast the function pointer with `(moDerives)` like this:

```
hnext = Miscmath::odeint((moDerivs)&QuintCosmos::propagateHistoryInTau, this);
```

This allows it to compile, but it fails at runtime with:

> Exception thrown at 0x001E7148 in cmb-easy.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000006C.

So, bottom line, does anyone know how to accomplish this: execute a member function from a base class?

Comment: I'd advice reading up on `virtual` functions as a starting point.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why was it done this way? If you're using inheritance, then … use it? `virtual` functions exist for a reason.

Comment: A class like **QuintCosmos** can have one, two or many functions that match this signature.  Any one of them can be a parameter to **odeint**.  Please give me an idea of how the virtual function helps here.

Comment: I don't understand. Why not just take `std::function<void(const double, const double*, double*)` and pass `std::bind(&QuintCosmos::propagateHistoryInTau, this)`? You can't convert a function pointer of `QuintCosmos` to function pointer of `Mathobject` object and call it inside method of `Miscmath` type.... And I would really consider the future of the original author that suggested to do `(moDerivs)&`

Comment: @KamilCuk - Keep in mind, I didn't write this.  It's a huge library I'm trying to port.  I can't call a static function because this function will sometimes use member fields.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] that works using `g++` or `clang++` but gives that error using MSVC? It's hard to guess how it's supposed to work otherwise.

Comment: "_What part don't you understand?_" - Well, I find that a short snippet of actual working code gives more information than text describing it.

Comment: @Quarkly [this is what KamilCuk means](https://godbolt.org/z/saUgWy)

Comment: e.g.: It will handle member data just fine

Comment: Looks like the sort of stuff that comes out of Goldman Sachs to me. You may as well migrate to using `std::function` and `virtual`.

Comment: @CássioRenan - That looks promising.  Let me try it out.

Comment: `Cosmos` and `QuintCosmos` *do* inherit from `Mathobject`, right?  And the object used (`mo`) *is* actually an instance of `QuintCosmos` (from the error message)?

Comment: @DavisHerring - Correct.  Mathobject -> Cosmos -> QuintCosmos.  But, no, the object **mo** is an instance of the base class *Mathobject*.

Comment: @Quarkly: Then it’s undefined behavior to invoke a member function that the (dynamic type of the) object does not in fact have.  Pointers to member functions are complicated in general, so it’s not surprising that the behavior differs between implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I got all that.  I know what you're saying.  If this was my code, it'd be different.  I'm looking for ideas here that will capture the original, half-cocked idea of generic function pointers so I can get this relic to run long enough to reverse engineer it.

Comment: @Quarkly: You’re not going to do better than “run the original in a VM or so until you’ve fixed it” for that.